# Shortcut to Shutdown in Windows 8

Tags: windows-8

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I shutdown Windows 8?](https://superuser.com/questions/491008/how-do-i-shutdown-windows-8)

Shortcut to Shutdown in Windows 8?

Something that I can place on desktop, taskbar or even a keyboard shortcut!

Answer (score 2):

Somebody made a program [here](http://www.eightforums.com/general-discussion/12033-windows-8-shutdown-tiles.html) that you may find relevant.

[image]

You can manually make a shutdown script by

1. Open notepad and pasting the following text `C:\Windows\System32\shutdown.exe -s -t 00`
2. Save the file as `shutdownScript.bat`
3. When you run this script it will shutdown your computer, make a shortcut to the script

Comment: This should work a way, but looking for desktop, taskbar or a keyboard shortcut.

Comment: Keep the shutdownScript.bat file on the desktop and click on it. I don't find why that isn't viable.